Question on rank of matrix to system of linear equation

Consider the linear system $A x = b$, where $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix, $x$ is an $n \times 1$ vector of unknowns, and $b$ is an $m \times 1$ vector. Further, suppose there exists an $m \times 1$ vector $c$ such that the linear system $A x = c$ has NO solution. Then, which of the following statements is / are necessarily TRUE?
(A) If $m \le n$ and $d$ is the first column of $A$, then the linear system $A x = d$ has a unique solution.
(B) If $m \ge n$, then ${\rm rank} A < n$.
(C) ${\rm rank} A < m$.
(D) If $m > n$, then the linear system $A x = 0$ has a solution other than $x = 0$.

It's multiple select answer (more than one option can be correct). Given answer is (C).
Now my thought process:
For Option (A):
As $d$ linear combination of one of the column of $A$ then there will be infinite solutions so (A) should be true.
For Option (B):
As we have $m \ge n$, I took $m = 3$, $n = 2$ and as we know for $A x = c$ matrix is giving no solution meaning one row must be zero, in this case we can make matrix which can have ${\rm rank} A = n$. This makes option (B) false. (As we need necessarily true)
For Option (C):
For $A x = c$ No solution the given $A$ matrix must be Inconsistent and since there will be a row with $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 | \text{ nonzero} \end{pmatrix}$ which can be enough to conclude option (C) is true.
Now I can't prove option (D) is correct or not.
Please check if my reasoning is correct or not and give your point of views also and what do you think why option (D) is false?

Please edit your post and use MathJax to format your question.

Give explicit counterexamples to convince yourself and others that a statement is false.
We assume $A \in \mathbb{M}_{m \times n} (\mathbb{R})$, and $b, c \in \mathbb{R}^m$ such that the equation $A x = c$ has no solution.
(A) is false. Take $A = 0$. In fact, there does not exist any matrices with $m \le n$ and $A x = d$ has a unique solution. For if $\dim {\rm nul} A = 0$ (which is implied by the fact that $A x = d$ has a unique solution), then by the rank-nullity theorem, ${\rm rank} A \ge m \implies {\rm rank} A = m$, which contradicts the hypothesis that $A x = c$ has no solution for some $c \in \mathbb{R}^m$.
(B) is false. Take $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$. However, there are matrices with $m \ge n$ but ${\rm rank} A < n$. One example is $A = 0$ (here, $m = 1 \ge n = 1$, and ${\rm rank} A = 0 < n$).
(C) is true. This follows from the fact that ${\rm col} A$ is a strict subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$ (the strictness is observed by $c$), which means ${\rm rank} A < m$.
(D) is false. Take the same example as the one in (B). However, there are matrices with $m > n$ and $A x = 0$ has a nontrivial solution. One example is $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ (here, $m = 3 > n = 2$ and the nontrivial vector $x = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$ solves $A x = 0$).

The equation $Ax = c$ not having any solutions means no linear combination of the columns of $A$ can form the vector $c$
In the case of option D, since $m \gt n$, the set of the columns of $A$ is smaller than the basis size of the $\mathbb{R}^m$, hence we cannot comment on the linear dependence of the columns, since $c$ could just lie in the space outside of the span of the columns which is definitely not empty
